# Store XML-String in Tag of XML-Document

Tags: xml, web-services

I have a Website using a Webservice(JS(Ajax) -> PHP) wich uses a Webservice (ASP.NET).

If an error occures in PHP, this is sent back to the client. If PHP gets an Error(XML) from ASP, I want to pass it to the client in a tag of my PHP-XML-error to offer further information.

So for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<PHPanswer>
  <error>It's not my fault!</error>

    <asperror> 
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
      <error>
        <whatever></whatever>
        <someinfo></someinfo>
      </error>
    </asperror>
</PHPanswer>
```

I want the Client (Client uses a XML-Reader) to treat this

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
      <error>
        <whatever></whatever>
        <someinfo></someinfo>
      </error>
```

like a string. (Probably parsing that string later, Like: Parse the message, take tag "asperror", parse the asperror).
So my first attempt was this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<PHPanswer>
  <errorcode>or whatever</errorcode>

    <asperror> <![CDATA[
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
      <error>
        <whatever></whatever>
        <someinfo></someinfo>
      </error>
      ]]>
    </asperror>
</PHPanswer>
```

It didn't work, and i checked it with the code-highlighting of Notepad++. Everything was consideret a string, exept

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

This of course made the xml invalid.
So: how else can I solve this? 
If possible I don't want to have to process the ASP-XML in PHP.

Comment: Try adding a double quote around the xml so it really looks like a string.

Comment: This does not seem to work, The "<?..." is still considered xml, not string. If i encode the brackets (like &lt;), would i have to redo this on the client or would it work?